# Speed up hive join on string values

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm running the code below in hive trying to join two tables on a field "word".  It's taking forever and I'm wondering what I could do to speed it up.  In one table the "word" field has a mix of upper and lower case letters, in the other table it is all upper case.

```
Code:

set hive.exec.compress.output=false;
set hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS newTable;
CREATE TABLE newTable AS
SELECT
      bh.inkey,
      bh.prid,
      bh.hname,
      bh.ptype,
      bh.band,
      bh.sles,
      bh.num_ducts,
      urg.R_NM

from table1 AS bh
INNER JOIN table2 AS urg
    ON LOWER(bh.word)=LOWER(urg.word);
```

Comment: how does it looks like the data distrubution in both tables for the columnd word? what are the most repeated values in both tables?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a temp table based on table1 with word in upper case. Then join this table to table2 without using any string function since table2.word is all upper case.  Aside from table1 and table2 as large, the string function lower is also causing the slowness in your query.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpTable;
CREATE TABLE tmpTable AS
SELECT bh.word,
      bh.inkey,
      bh.prid,
      bh.hname,
      bh.ptype,
      bh.band,
      bh.sles,
      bh.num_ducts
from table1 AS bh;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS newTable;
CREATE TABLE newTable AS
SELECT
      tmp.inkey,
      tmp.prid,
      tmp.hname,
      tmp.ptype,
      tmp.band,
      tmp.sles,
      tmp.num_ducts,
      urg.R_NM
from tmpTable AS tmp
INNER JOIN table2 AS urg
    ON tmp.word=urg.word;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had once a problem that my join condition was too complex and hive ended up using only 1 reducer to calculate it. It may be the same here because of the `LOWER` transformations. Can you check how many reducers is hive using ?

You can use CTE to do the `LOWER` as a pre step and have a trivial join condition :

```
CREATE TABLE newTable AS
with 
    table1_lower as (SELECT *, lower(word) as lword from table1),
    table2_lower as (SELECT *, lower(word) as lword from table2)
select
    bh.inkey,
    bh.prid,
    bh.hname,
    bh.ptype,
    bh.band,
    bh.sles,
    bh.num_ducts,
    urg.R_NM
from table1_lower AS bh
INNER JOIN table2_lower AS urg
    ON bh.lword=urg.lword;
```